# What is the difference between out of stock and 0 of stock?

Tags: products-management, stock, quantity

What is the difference between out of stock and 0 of stock?

I have an extension that automatically displays products from the same category as related products, however it displays products that are out of stock as well.

I checked in system configurations/inventory/stock options
Display Out of Stock Products NO

In it's code it does not check for quantity left, it checks for stock value. So do I need to set up a stock value for every product? If so how do I do it?

I found this in the code of the extension

```
            $products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
            Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($products);

            $this->setData('related_products', $products);
```

Comment: That depends on the extension that you use. Without the code we can't help you more.

Comment: yes I agree with @ZvonimirBurić Please update the code then and then we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these attributes are related to products which have managed stock, this information is stored in the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table.

Specifically what you are refering to is:

`is_in_stock`: This determines whether a product is saleable, it can have a value of 0 (not available), or 1 (available). Essentially, this tells the customer whether or not a product is available, or *Out of Stock*.

`qty`: This is a positive or negative decimal value which indicates available stock quantity.

For these to come into effect, the product in specific must have stock managed set to yes.

**The difference between the two:**

Some products are back-orderable (i.e do not become out of stock when reaching negative `qty` values (handled by the `use_config_backorders` & `backorders` fields))

Also, some products have specific `qty` levels at which they become out of stock (handled by the `use_config_min_qty` & `min_qty` fields)

Magento offers further information on this topic over here:

[MagentoCommerce | Managing Stock for Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/managing-stock-for-configurable-products)